# How to get the content area height dynamically through angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an image as shown in the snapshot. I need to get the content area height. I am using AngularJS. Does anyone have an idea on how to do so?

[image]

Comment: Just posted a few possibilities. Let me know if one of those fits your needs!

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a JavaScript question than an AngularJS. You should be able to do something like:

```
var clientHeight = document.getElementById('myDiv').clientHeight;
```

or

```
var offsetHeight = document.getElementById('myDiv').offsetHeight;
```

or if you're trying to get the height of the image itself:

```
var img = document.getElementById('img');
var height = img.height;
```